# Why do differential Equations with purely imaginary roots only have periodic solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is more of a conceptual question, in the Book Differential Equations with historical Notes by Simmons and Introduction to ODE's by Howell it is mentioned that (though in slightly different ways) that if the characteristic polynomial yields only purely imaginary roots, the solutions will be periodic.

I solved a lot of exercises and went down many rabbit holes. I don't see why.

Would someone here enlighten me?

I feel like this has some Eigenvalue connection and Transformations which end up undoing themselves.
But I couldn't think any further, please also feel free to shoot down this idea.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: given the roots of the characteristic polynomial, what does a solution look like?

Comment: Hmm.. I've been playing with your hint, the only thing that I can come up with that makes some what sense is if I have $r_1, r_2...., r_n$ for n roots it will be something like $(x-r_1)(x-r_2).....(x-r_n)$ does this go into the right direction? @user619894 ?

Comment: I meant the solution to the ODE.  Think how the polynomial is related to the ODE.

Comment: I disagree with the statement. The solutions based on complex roots must be _oscillatory_, but not necessarily periodic. To enforce the latter, you must have only _purely imaginary_ roots.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I am sorry, the statements in both books actually say purely imaginary roots and not complex. It was my negligence here that didn't think of the difference. I do still not see why though.

Comment: @user619894 hmm, the roots are the values for lambda that map to the null space?

Comment: Well, what is $e^{it}$?

Comment: @IvanNeretin $cos(t) + isin(t)$ ?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Oh, I think I'm having a lightbulb moment, but not super bright yet. Because $e^{it}$ when differentiated is periodic, i.e. it comes back every 4 derivatives, the connection is somewhere there? I am sorry, I appreciate that you guys bear with me.

Comment: What's important is that it is periodic in $t$: you add $2\pi$ and you end up where you were before.

Comment: @IvanNeretin thank you. I see that. But I have some trouble to see why this would always lead to periodic solutions. Is it because, if it's purely imaginary, it can always be somehow expressed in terms of a multiple of $e^{it}$? Thanks again!

Comment: "Multiple" is a wrong word. See, $e^{2it}$ is not a multiple of $e^{it}$. But it is also periodic, albeit with a different period.

Comment: hmm @IvanNeretin thank you. I appreciate it. I am getting a feel but still can't quite grasp it yet. Maybe I need to sleep on it for the insight to sink in.

Comment: The claim is wrong in general. While you can always find periodic basis solutions, the general solution is pseudo-periodic, as the frequencies will in general not be commensurable (rational multiples of each other or integer multiples of a base frequency).

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you. Is there a simple explanation why it is guaranteed that there always are periodic solutions?

Comment: Do you accept that $u''+k^2u=0$ has periodic solutions?

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes, that's harmonic oscillations right?

Comment: And your equation itself is real, that is, all coefficients are real?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I think there can be complex coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was already commented, you can factorize the differential equation as
$$
a_n(D-ib_1)(D-ib_2)\dots(D-ib_n)u=0.
$$
The solution for each factor $(D-ib_k)u=0\implies u(t)=ce^{ib_kt}$ is periodic with period $T_k=\frac{2\pi}{b_k}$.

That the factorization is possible is a consequence of the coefficients being constant. For the same reason the factors commute. This means that a solution of a factor is also a solution of the DE.

All solutions are linear combinations of the above basis solutions. Such a linear combination is only periodic if all periods are integer multiples of a base period, else they are quasi-periodic, with a discrete spectrum but no repeating parts in the graph.